# How can I use AsyncStorage.getItem() + JSON.parse() with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use JSON.parse in my if statement, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string | null' and 'boolean' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

I know there's a possibility of the the AsyncStorage.getItem return as null, and I use `JSON.parse()` to convert `'true'` or `'false'` to `true` or `false`.

AsyncStorage can only save things as strings, so you have to use `JSON.stringify()` when setting and `JSON.parse()` when getting. How do I fix the error?

**Query.tsx**

```
let previouslyCachedEndReached = await AsyncStorage.getItem('endReached');


    // Check If End Has Been Reached
    if (JSON.parse(previouslyCachedEndReached !== true)) {


      // Do something

    }
```

I've event tried adding typings like this, but the error still occurs:

```
const previouslyCachedEndReached: string | boolean | null = await AsyncStorage.getItem('endReached');
```

Comment: you have an error in this line:
`if (JSON.parse(previouslyCachedEndReached !== true))` - the end parentheses are in the wrong place.  Typescript is helping you by informing you that your code has an error.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake, but was driving me crazy